# Immutable.fromJS(firebaseAuthUserResult) fails and is not an immutable

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, immutable.js

I am trying to `Immutable.fromJS` a firebase auth `user` object.. this fails and returns a standard object..

I am assuming it is due to the firebase `user` object contains functions .. or suchlike?

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
  if (user) {
    console.log('received', user);

    // following returns an object (the same as the received .. not an immutable!?)
    console.log('immutable.fromJS', Immutable.fromJS(user));

    // the following fails as it is not an immutable so toJS does not exist!
    console.log('immutable.toJS', Immutable.fromJS(user).toJS());
  }
});
```

Any tips appreciated!

```
"dependencies": {
  "firebase": "^3.6.7",
  "immutable": "^3.8.1",
}
```

yarn:

```
resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/firebase/-/firebase-3.6.7.tgz#7708dc6ddaa313415bbc5213116c597b21567ab2"
resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/immutable/-/immutable-3.8.1.tgz#200807f11ab0f72710ea485542de088075f68cd2"
```

Currently as a pms the state is as is and not immutable.

Answer (score 0):

The `fromJS()` function only works with *plain objects* and *arrays* since it only creates immutable Maps and Lists respectively. Think about JSON data - this can be passed.

Answer (score 0):

Use user.toJSON() to get a valid JSON that can be passed to fromJS()